# C++ divide a number to display at most 60 chars for different rolls of a dice

Tags: c++, count, format, cout, dice

I am told to roll a die a large number of times (a few thousand) at first once then record the amount of times each value occurs and create a makeshift histogram displaying an X for a roll of that number, e.g. rolling 3 `1`'s, 2 `2`'s, and 5 `3`'s might be like this:

```
1 xxx
2 xx
3 xxxxx
```

What I am trying to do is find a way to divide the X's up so that at most 60 X's appear next to the number.

I have two instances, rolling a single die recording 1-6, and then two dice and recording the sum which is in the range 2-12 (11 values).

Originally I tried to just divide the number of rolls by 360 (6 possible values for 1 die, 60 total Xs) to get the number of occurrences each X represented then taking my count for a roll (say I rolled 1 2047 times) and dividing by this value so if I rolled the dice 12000 times then the value of each X would be 12000/360 = 33 (the .3333 is dropped due to integer division) then I would display 2047 / 33 X's but that yields 62.

Anyone have a better way to do this?

I tried 11*60 for the two dice approach and that was just way off.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework, so here's a hint:  Figure out what the largest value you need to display is, then use that along with the maximum length to display (60) to get a ratio to calculate the length of each line of output.

Comment: I can't figure out the largest value, there is no roof

Comment: @user2763113 "Figure out" means to have your program look at the data and remember what the largest value in the array is.

Comment: Do you mean the roll which occurred the most? For example if I roll between 1 and 3 and get 500 1s, 2400 2s, and 5000 3s I would base the number off of the 5000 for the 3s?

Comment: I tried what I just mentioned and it works for 1-6 but weird stuff happens in 2-12 and I ended up with 61